# Android studio is shows project path with Yen symbols instead \?

Tags: android, windows, android-studio

I have a problem as `Yen` symbol in android studio file path instead `\` . Command prompt shows everything fine. But the issue only appears in Android Studio and I have recently reinstall it and no change was made. Maybe someone could help me?

** Screenshot of android studio file path**

[image: android studio file path]

**Screenshot of my region settings**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was connected with Android Studio Fonts

Go to the Settings > Appearance > You have to select different Front

And after Applying check out if the Yen still appears, if so then change the Font to another one.